# How to fix? PHP variable not shows values inside function

Tags: php, function

I want to pass the variable in a function but get an error :

Working Example :

```
$text_line1 = function (TextToImage $handler) {
    $line_first ="Vasim";
    $handler->add($line_first)
            ->position(250, 100)
            ->font(24, __DIR__ . '/Roboto-Black.ttf')
            ->color(0, 0, 0);
};
```

Not Working :

```
$line_second = $imageMeta[2];
$text_line2 = function (TextToImage $handler) {

    $handler->add($line_second)
            ->position(250, 150)
            ->font(20, __DIR__ . '/Roboto-Black.ttf')
            ->color(0, 0, 0);
};
```

Comment: Sure, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @pavel Is there way to fix. I am not getting trying since yesterday.

Comment: Please read the link I've posted you. There is an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the "USE" keyword (for anonymous functions, as you are using in your second example). This allows additional variables from the parent scope to be passed into the closure. Its usage can be a little tricky, see [the official PHP anonymous function documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for more information (specifically, see example #3).

```php
$line_second = $imageMeta[2];
$text_line2 = function (TextToImage $handler) use ($line_second) {

    $handler->add($line_second)
            ->position(250, 150)
            ->font(20, __DIR__ . '/Roboto-Black.ttf')
            ->color(0, 0, 0);
};
```

Comment: I have try other solution but wont work. Just forget about use keyword. Its works

Answer (score -1):

If it is a class then access the variable by adding `this` keyword. If a normal function and add `global` in front of it to access a global variable.

Comment: `this` won't work, `global` is hell - please forget that someting like `global` exist.

Comment: pavel, I am getting confused

Comment: @pavel I am totally lost. if you can share solution that be nice.